# Drupal 7 -Resize image from URL

Tags: media

At present I am working on a demo site. I am pulling in sample images from from lorempixel for place holders. That is working great. In my content type I have an image field and it includes the url to the image like this: http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-605-186-6.jpg

I will be creating views soon and I want to adjust the image size using image styles. How can I apply the image style to the text field that holding the url? Is this possible, if so, how? if not, is there another way to accomplish this?

I don't want to create various image size, just adjust them as they are being referenced.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the url to the image like this: .....  - your example is missing

Answer (score 0):

For this one - I am going to adjust the size via css in each of the views.  Would still like to know if the above is possible, but this will resolve my current issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use [image_style_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) function to create a url to your image with your custom image style.